# Accessors in nodejs c++ addons

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

How to use setter and getter for a global variable 'X' in a C++ extension to a Node.js?

I am getting undefined 'x' in getter and setter methods.

Trying to execute `Accessors` program for `Static Global Variables` from this [link](https://developers.google.com/v8/embed).

I have successfully written a tiny module that adds and multiplies the two given numbers.

following is my code

Init(entry point) method contains-

`exports->SetAccessor(String::New("x"), XGet, XSet);`

and above that I have following setter and getter.

```
Handle<Value> XGet(Local<String> property, const AccessorInfo& info){
return Integer::New(x);
}

void XSet(Local<String> property, Local<Value> value, const AccessorInfo& info){
x = value->Int32Value();
}
```

On compilation it says - `‘x’ was not declared in this scope`

Comment: Your C++ is assigning to a variable `x`. Do you have `int x;` or `int32_t x;` somewhere?

Comment: thanks for reply, no `int x` in the program, my understanding is - x will be defined by 'SetAccessor' method, am i wrong ? not even `int32_t x` anywhere.

Comment: You'll definitely need to define it somewhere, just like you'd have `var x` or something in JavaScript. In the case of the example you are looking at, you just need `int32_t x;` in your C++ file above your XGet/XSet functions somewhere.

Comment: thanks, it worked, great ! but will you please tell me that, why it was need and it was not given in the documentation I am referring to...also my understanding was wrong, i made that variable global for now, is any other good way ?

Comment: also, it worked for both `int x` and `int32_t x`, can you suggest me what more I should read about using v8 APIs and relative stuff ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `'x' was not declared in this scope` pretty much pins it down. Your code and the example page you are looking at are explicitly titled `Accessing Static Global Variables`, so I think they assume you already have such a variable `x` defined, which you want to access/mutate via JS.

So the quick fix is the add `int32_t x;` in your C++ file somewhere above `XGet` and `XSet`.

The [node documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) has a little bit of information on this, and the section titled `Wrapping C++ objects` might be a good place for you to start if you want to work with instances of an object rather than single global variables.

Comment: Correct, `In the preceding example the variables were static and global.` is the first line in their next section called as `Accessing Dynamic Variables`. Thanks a ton. I will also look into `node documentation::wrapping c++ objects`.